# Trying to determine relative path location between Java and Tomcat

Tags: java, java-7, javax

I have some old code that I am trying to stand back up. When I deploy the code it errors out saying: nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
Name [twiddyApiConfigPath] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [twiddyA
piConfigPath].

The code is as follows:

```
String configPath = (String) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/twiddyApiConfigPath");
```

My question, is this looking for an environmental variable named twiddyApiConfigPath to load the file from?

Update:

So it sounds like it's a relative path. I still don't understand where I need to place the prop file in order to make it reachable by the application within the tomcat hierarchy.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19747-01/819-0079/dgjndi.html does this help?

Comment: @Pomagranite So it sounds like it's a relative path? I still don't understand where I need to place the props file on the tomcat server?